# How can I capture errors from chrome dev console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, error-handling

I see errors like this `[DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #element_id` in the dev console, but how can I capture this errors?

For "normal" errors I already registered a global error handling, but this special chrome errors are not reported?

example: global js error handling
https://gist.github.com/voku/79cc77eab5da0374092a7a3a09da16c1

Comment: Those are not JavaScript errors so not going to be triggered with window.onerror.

Comment: I know, but how can I capture this errors? Because if I had statistics / error reports about this issues I would know where to fix it. :-/

Comment: It is part of chrome, they do not expose it to JavaScript. Or if they do, it is some hidden api, but I doubt it is.